# Обновление таблицы в базе данных из таблицы DataGridView

Tags: c#, база-данных, sql-server

Необходимо сделать так, чтобы можно было обновить запись в БД при нажатии на кнопку и изменяя записи в DataGridView. Я поискал и наткнулся на SqlCommandBuilder, но я не могу понять как его использовать с моей таблицей DataGridView. В общем, хочу обновлять всю таблицу вне зависимости от того, в каких строках я сделал изменения. [image: Вот сам DataGridView]

Ну и хочется вызывать всё это обновление в отдельном методе.

```
public static void UpdateDataRealEstate(DataTable dtable)
{
    using (Connection = new SqlConnection(connectionStringToDatabase))
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: интерфейс примера]

Создадим такой класс для работы с БД

```
public class DataContext
{
    private const string _cnnString = @"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;" +
        "Initial Catalog=DatabaseDGVDisconnected;Integrated Security=True;" +
        "Connect Timeout=60;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;" +
        "ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False";

    public DataTable GetRealEstatesOrNull()
    {
        DataTable table = null;
        try
        {
            using (var cnn = new SqlConnection(_cnnString))
            using (var cmd = cnn.CreateCommand())
            using (var adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM RealEstates";
                table = new DataTable();
                int affected = adp.Fill(table);
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        return table;
    }

    public DataTable UpdateRealEstatesOrNull(DataTable dataTable)
    {
        DataTable resultTable = null;
        try
        {
            using (var cnn = new SqlConnection(_cnnString))
            using (var cmd = cnn.CreateCommand())
            using (var adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM RealEstates";
                using (var bld = new SqlCommandBuilder(adp))
                {
                    int affected = adp.Update(dataTable);
                    resultTable = dataTable;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        return resultTable;
    }
}
```

Код формы такой

```
public partial class FormMain : Form
{
    private readonly DataContext _dataContext;
    public FormMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _dataContext = new DataContext();

        _dataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        _columnCity.DataPropertyName = "City";
        _columnStreet.DataPropertyName = "Street";
        _columnBuilding.DataPropertyName = "Building";
        _columnApartment.DataPropertyName = "Apartment";

        this.Load += FormMain_Load;
        _buttonSave.Click += ButtonSave_Click;
    }

    private void FormMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var dataTable = _dataContext.GetRealEstatesOrNull();
        if (dataTable != null)
        {
            _dataGridView.DataSource = dataTable;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Не удалось получить данные из БД", "Ошибка",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

    private void ButtonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var oldTable = (DataTable)_dataGridView.DataSource;
        var newTable = _dataContext.UpdateRealEstatesOrNull(oldTable);
        if (newTable != null)
        {
            _dataGridView.DataSource = newTable;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Не удалось сохранить данные в БД", "Ошибка",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
}
```

Репозиторий проекта [здесь](https://github.com/bulsond/SOrusExamples2/tree/master/WindowsFormsDGVDisconnected).

Comment: Код не сработал.

Comment: @sakyrade  надо только уточнить чей код не сработал. Мой код сработал и работает иначе я бы его в качестве ответа не показывал.

Comment: всё работает. Я запрос неправильно поставил. Спасибо.